# Here is a function to switch to dark mode, but the last condition does not work

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```js
const btnDarkLight = (btn) => {
  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches(btn)) {
      document.querySelector(btn);
      let moon = document.body.classList.toggle("oscuro");
    }

    if (e.target.matches(btn)) {

      if (this.value === "") {
        document.querySelector(btn).innerText = "☀️";
      } else {
        document.querySelector(btn).innerText = "";
      }
    }
  })
}

btnDarkLight("#btn-light-dark");
```

```html
<button id="btn-light-dark" class="button-dark" type="button"></button>
```

I am trying to change the icon inside the button when dark mode is activated, but the condition doesn't work.

Comment: Log `this.value` in console. That's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this. first, don't create a listener inside a callable function - you'll end up creating many, many of them. Second, you don't need to `querySelect` the button element because it is passed into your function. third, providing the exact same conditional `if` is redundant and unneeded. There is too much to resolve.

Comment: @RandyCasburn There's nothing wrong with putting the code inside a function, unless the function is called multiple times (i.e. don't add an event listener inside another listener).

Comment: `this.value` should be `this.innerText`.

Comment: @Barmar -  Then put it in an IIFE. The wrapper function is not necessary at all and suggests it is called multiple time (potentially).

Comment: Just look at the class on the body, not the text

Comment: @RandyCasburn Naming functions is helpful to make the code more understandable. You don't have to limit named functions to code that's used repeatedly.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to test `e.target.innerText`, not `this.value`. Since you defined the listener using an arrow function, `this` is inherited from the calling environment, it's not the event target. And the contents of a button are in its text, not value.

```js
const btnDarkLight = (btn) => {
  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches(btn)) {
      let moon = document.body.classList.toggle("oscuro");
      if (e.target.innerText === "") {
        e.target.innerText = "☀️";
      } else {
        e.target.innerText = "";
      }
    }
  })
}

btnDarkLight("#btn-light-dark");
```

```html
<button id="btn-light-dark" class="button-dark" type="button"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a lot of work, just do this with css and toggle the appropriate class(es).

```js
document.querySelector("#btn-light-dark").addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.toggle("day");
  this.classList.toggle("night");
});
```

```css
.day:before {
  content:'☀️'
}
.night:before {
  content:''
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-light-dark" class="day"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the class and no rely on the text of the button.

```js
const btnDarkLight = (btn) => {
  const btnElem = document.querySelector(btn);

  const setText = () => {
    const text = document.body.classList.contains('oscuro') ? '' : '☀️';
    btnElem.textContent = text;
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches(btn)) {
      document.body.classList.toggle('oscuro');
      setText();
    }
  });

  setText();

}

btnDarkLight("#btn-light-dark");
```

```css
.oscuro {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-light-dark" class="button-dark" type="button"></button>
```

or just rely on CSS

```js
const btnDarkLight = (btn) => {
  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches(btn)) {
      document.body.classList.toggle('oscuro');
    }
  });
}

btnDarkLight("#btn-light-dark");
```

```css
.oscuro {
  background-color: black;
}

#btn-light-dark::after {
  content: '☀️';
}

body.oscuro #btn-light-dark::after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-light-dark" class="button-dark" type="button"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code below

```js
document.getElementById('btn-light-dark').addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    if (e.target.innerText === "") {
            e.target.innerText = "☀️";
            document.body.classList.toggle("oscuro")
          } else e.target.innerText = "";
})
```

```html
<button id="btn-light-dark" class="button-dark" type="button"></button>
```